# Можно ли Java класс разбить на несколько файлов?

Tags: ооп, eclipse, java

На Java принято классы помещать в отдельные файлы. Можно один файл использовать для двух классов. А можно ли разбить класс на несколько файлов, т.е. тела некоторых методов вынести в отдельные файлы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если класс "очень большой", значит с большой вероятностью там есть функционал, который можно (и нужно разбить) на пару классов поменьше. В этом случае сразу улучшается поддержка кода и восприимчивость его пользователем.
Если же есть код, который завязан на этот большой класс, то можно сделать так. делаются небольшие классы для каждой подзадачи, а "большой класс" просто содержит эти классы в приватных полях. А свои публичные методы просто переадресовывает. И если все правильно сделать, то у "большого класса" пропадут все приватные методы - они ему будут просто не нужны.

Answer (score 3):

Нет. Никогда. Never ever ever ever. Это очень плохая идея. И поэтому это нельзя.

В конечном счёте, если класс стал так сложен, что его хочется разбить на несколько файлов, то это плохой класс. Выбросьте его немедленно, пока не стало слишком поздно.

Comment: В C++ можно и это удобно, когда класс очень большой. Чем бы это могло обернуться, если бы можно было?

Comment: Если класс очень большой, то его надо немедленно на расстрел вместе с тем, кто написал его таким большим.

Comment: Один файл для двух классов можно... Не для двух public конечно, но можно.

Comment: Насколько помню, в С++ можно определять методы класса в разных модулях, но определение самого класса только в одном файле.

Comment: Идея может и не слишком плохая, но у разработчиков руки не дошли (или усложнять не захотели) связывать один .class (загружаемый) с несколькими .java (единицы компиляции). 

Меня наоборот раздражает, что несколько маленьких (и родственных по "смыслу" задачи) public нельзя поместить в один файл. 

(или как-то можно ?)

Comment: Нет, нельзя. И это на мой взгляд искуственное ограничение. Видимо сделано для некоего баланса. А то что руки не дошли.. надеюсь не дойдут никогда до такого. Если начнут вводить такие вещи в Java, то это будет означать, что яве наступил конец.

Comment: Сейчас я понимаю, что действительно, это преднамеренное ограничение. Дкмаю любой объект можно разбить на подобъекты... и так далее до элементарных объектов.  
  
В C++ определение класса находится только в одном файле (методы можно только объявить), а методы можно определить в разных файлах, мне и это нужно было. Но т.к. на Java методы определяются вместе с объявлением, то разделить класс на файлы никак не получиться. Кроме как искуственными методами.

Answer (score 0):

Как костыль, если ооооочень нужно, можно сделать через наследование. Базовый класс (или классы) в одном файле или файлах (можно сделать как абстрактные), а производный - в другом. Можно методы базового класса сделать final, чтобы неповадно было переопределять.

Если ляпнул что-то не то, да простят меня уважаемые гуру.

Comment: Ну совсеееем костыль. Иногда такой подход удобен если часть кода генерируется какой-нибудь тулой, а часть пишется руками.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю у автора был вопрос относительно самой функциональности Java. Например, в C# есть модификатор `parcial` именно для такой цели. И в [официальной документации](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#partial-classes) даже расписано:

> Разделяемые классы
> Существует несколько ситуаций, когда желательно разделение определения класса.
> При работе над большими проектами распределение класса между различными файлами позволяет нескольким программистам работать с ним одновременно.
> При работе с использованием автоматически создаваемого источника код можно добавлять в класс без повторного создания файла источника. Visual Studio использует этот подход при создании форм Windows Forms, кода оболочки веб-службы и т. д. Можно создать код, который использует эти классы, без необходимости изменения файла, созданного в Visual Studio.
> При использовании генераторов источников для создания дополнительных функциональных возможностей в классе.
> Чтобы разделить определение класса, используйте модификатор ключевого слова partial, как показано ниже:...

Comment: Вот в Java такой функциональности нет. Так что только декомпозиция.